# having the github in sync with svn

Tags: git, svn, github

Historically the owner of an opensource projet use svn and want to continue to use svn.
New people want to use github to use all the DVCS and github tools to work together.

We can get svn and commit regularly to github but in this case we loose svn commits and comments.

Is it possible to have an automatic system that takes new svn commit, and recreate all the commits in the github with the username and comments?

We don't need to put our changes back to the svn (no commit to svn, svn is just read only for us).

Comment: Are you aware of `git-svn`?http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into your SVN server. Then a Git interface for the SVN repository is created. You need just setup the read/write access to that newly created Git repository.
Every commit pushed to Git interface is translated to SVN revision and vice versa. And SubGit cares about concurrency. So this Git interface may be used by your new people.

If you need a read-only mirror on GitHub, you may run "git push --all --tags  " in some cron script to push from a local Git interface to the GitHub.

Unfortunately I don't know any concurrent-safe solution which would allow to push to GitHub and would allow to commit to your local SVN repository at the same time by another developer without letting the SVN and GitHub histories to diverge.